# Data Manipulation in R (going through rows)

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

let say I have

```
df <- data.frame(obs=c('1', '2', '3', '4'),
                 distance=c('1.11','2.22','9.99','3.33'))
```

and I would like to specify the condition to identify outlier

```
outlier <- if(distance[distance>5]){
  print("YES")
} else {
  print("NO")
}
```

The code is currently look for the first element. What would the change needed so that the code would look through every row and check it against the condition where is distance is larger than 5, it will have a label of Yes next to it for a final result similar to this

```
df <- data.frame(obs=c('1', '2', '3', '4'),
                 distance=c('1.11','2.22','9.99','3.33'),
                 outlier=c('No','No','Yes','No'))
head(df)
```

Thank you

Comment: try `df %>% mutate(outlier = if_else(distance > 5, 'yes', 'no'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use tidyverse package.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(check = if_else(distance > 5, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
  filter(check == "Yes")
```